# filtering curse words from a sentence while iterating through an array of curse words

Tags: swift

```
var myDirtySentence = """
        Some dirty words like
        bleep and
        bloop
    """
var notAllowedWords = ["bleep","bloop"]
var myCleanSentence = ""
for i in 0..<notAllowedWords.count{
    myCleanSentence = myDirtySentence.replacingOccurrences(of:notAllowedWords[i], with: "****")
}

print(myCleanSentence)
```

It's only censoring the last index of array I want to filter all.

Comment: You should read up on the "Scunthorpe problem"

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things. First you need to start at index `0` of notAllowedWords. Also you're not saving the result of each pass through your loop so try something like this:

```
var myDirtySentence = """
        Some dirty words like
        bleep and
        bloop
    """
var notAllowedWords = ["bleep","bloop"]
var myCleanSentence = myDirtySentence
for i in 0..<notAllowedWords.count{
    myCleanSentence = myCleanSentence.replacingOccurrences(of:notAllowedWords[i], with: "****")
}

print(myCleanSentence)
```

We can also avoid dealing with an index altogether by iterating through the `notAllowedWords` directly. For example:

```
for badWord in notAllowedWords {
    myCleanSentence = myCleanSentence.replacingOccurrences(of:badWord, with: "****")
}
```